# Addplot doesn't accept color

Tags: pgfplots, color

I tried to plot a sequence with pgfplots but I cannot set the color:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Start}{1} %% start value
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{5} %% end value
  \begin{axis}[mark options={mark=x},only marks,axis lines=center,xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$a_n$,samples at={\Start,...,\End},xtick={0,1,...,\End},grid=both, minor y tick num=4,enlargelimits]
    \addplot[green] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \addplot[green] {1/x};%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What would be the proper way to specify the color here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\addplot+` instead of `\addplot`. The `\addplot` version overwrites the default settings with the given options (here only `green`) and hence the plot is not drawn at all.On the other hand `\addplot+` appends the options to the default ones.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Start}{1} %% start value
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{5} %% end value
  \begin{axis}[mark options={mark=x},only marks,axis lines=center,xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$a_n$,samples at={\Start,...,\End},xtick={0,1,...,\End},grid=both, minor y tick num=4,enlargelimits]
    \addplot+[green] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \addplot+[green] {1/x};%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works. But I don't understand why `\addplot` doesn't. If it overwrites the default settings, then giving no optional argument to it should set the options to nothing (which doesn't seem to be the case). Also it should be possible to write something like `\addplot[draw,green]` to make it work again. Can you explain this point a bit mor in detail?

Comment: @Julia It is rather `\addplot[]` that overwrites the defaults. A standalone `\addplot` doesn't do this. Additional `[]` clears up the existing style. A plus sign adds to the existing style.

Comment: @percusse. Ok. What would be the correct version of what I intended with `\addplot[draw,green]`?

Comment: @Julia `\addplot[green,mark=*] {1/x};`